# Don't clear the message edit history on pressing Esc in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

While I had been typing out a message, I had accidentally pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd> instead of <kbd>`</kbd>, which resulted in chat clearing the whole message I have written, *together with the edit history*, so pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> didn't help.

It would be nice if this pitfall was removed, or at least, if it didn't clear the edit history.

Comment: Sometimes it happens for me, because (one of) my browser have ESC  as the main control key (like Vim), so when I switch to another browser...

Comment: So the solution to feature requests that are unsolved for 4 years is a Chrome-specific userscript that hasn't been updated in years that doesn't even solve the problem of Esc key clearing everything. Good job SE.

Comment: I really don't see why this is marked as duplicate. Yes, the two questions are _related_ to the same functionality, but they are asking different things. One is looking to remove the clearing functionality altogether, whilst this is simple looking to make it improve it.